Select Most Recent Invoice Price for Customer versus Quote Price
I have two tables I would like to query and compare. I want to find the most recent price a customer has paid and compare it to the most recent price they were quoted for the same item but only returns results if the two prices are different. Below are some mock tables.
Table 1 (Invoices)



Customer
Item
Price
TranDate




1505
ABC
3.04
2024-5-17


2106
ABC
5.20
2024-4-01


1505
ABC
2.96
2024-1-16


1505
ABC
3.15
2023-12-15



Table 2 (Quotes)



Customer
Item
Price
TranDate




1505
ABC
2.96
2024-7-29


1505
ABC
3.08
2024-6-15



I can produce the individual queries that show the results similar to Table1 and Table2 above. It is the combining and most recent values that I am struggling with.
Results



Customer
Item
InvPrice
QuotePrice




1505
ABC
3.04
2.96



Script that I've tried.
SELECT Invoices.Customer, Invoices.Item, Invoices.Price AS [InvPrice], Quotes.Price AS [QuotePrice]
FROM Invoices
JOIN Quotes ON Quotes.Customer = Invoices.Customer
WHERE Quotes.Price <> Invoices.Price
AND Invoices.TranDate = (SELECT MAX(TranDate) FROM Invoices)
ORDER BY Customer

Thank you!

One way you can do this is:
with MostRecentInvoiced as (
select I.Customer,  I.Item, I.Price as InvoicedPrice,   I.TranDate as InvoicedDate
from Invoices I
where I.TranDate = (select max(TranDate) from Invoices I2 
                    where I.Customer=I2.Customer 
                      and I.Item=I2.Item)
                      )
, MostRecentQuoted as (
select Q.Customer,  Q.Item, Q.Price as QuotedPrice, Q.TranDate as QuotedDate
from Quotes Q
where Q.TranDate = (select max(TranDate) from Quotes Q2 
                    where Q.Customer=Q2.Customer 
                      and Q.Item=Q2.Item)
                      )
select I.Customer,  I.Item, I.InvoicedPrice, I.InvoicedDate, Q.QuotedPrice, Q.QuotedDate
from MostRecentInvoiced I
     inner join
     MostRecentQuoted Q
     on Q.Customer=I.Customer
     and Q.Item=I.Item
where I.InvoicedPrice <> Q.QuotedPrice

Here we prepare each set of 'most recent invoice', and 'most recent quote' for each customer and item separately; and then join them (internally SQLServer may not process them in this order but it helps to visualise).
My concerns for your script:

SELECT MAX(TranDate) subquery gets the latest invoice date regardless of which customer or which item it is,
your join also doesn't care if pairing up rows with the same item.

In relation to limiting results to just the 'Open' Quotes: if your intention is to exclude them from all consideration for this query; you need to add it to:

The main query (the one at the bottom)
The Quotes CTE main part 'From Quotes Q where Q.CloseDate is null`
The subquery in the Quotes CTE: from Quotes Q2 where Q2.CloseDate is null
On the other hand, if you want to consider open & closed Quotes for the comparison, but simply discard the result rows if the quote is now closed, you can add it to only the main query.


This worked great! I do have one question - it is returning all quotes (both open and closed). I have a column called CloseDate that is shows as null if it is not closed. Could I simply add Q.CloseDate is Null to my Q.TranDate where clause? Allowing only open quotes?

@Scott, added some guidance for the closedate treatment.

You can use ROW_NUMBER function to get the last records for both Invoice and Quotes table and use some subequeries to get the results you need. Alternatively, you can use CTE instead of subqueries.
The query bellow does the following with the invoices table.

Uses the ROW_NUMBER function to get the row number of each row. It partitions data by Customer and Item, then orders data by TranDate in descending order.
Filters the rows where RowNumber from step 1 equals to 1.
It does the same to the Quotes table to get the most recent record from Quotes table too.
Then we INNER JOIN quotes subquery to only include those rows in our result set that have matching quotes.
Finally, filters the data where quote and invoice prices are different.

Please note that this query will be slow on large data sets. A proper indexing in the tables should help, but the ROW_NUMBER function tends to be slow for large data sets in my experience.
SELECT 
    LastInvoice.Customer,
    LastInvoice.Item,
    LastInvoice.Price AS InvPrice,
    LastQuote.Price AS QuotePrice
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Customer, 
            Item, 
            Price, 
            TranDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, Item ORDER BY TranDate DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM Invoices
    ) AS GroupedResult
    WHERE GroupedResult.RowNumber = 1
) AS LastInvoice
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Customer, 
            Item, 
            Price, 
            TranDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, Item ORDER BY TranDate DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM Quotes
    ) AS GroupedResult
    WHERE GroupedResult.RowNumber = 1
) AS LastQuote
    ON LastQuote.Customer = LastInvoice.Customer
WHERE LastQuote.Price <> LastInvoice.Price


This is untested query,
SELECT Invoices.Customer, Invoices.Item, max(Invoices.Price) AS [InvPrice]
, (select top 1 Price from Quotes where  Quotes.Customer = Invoices.Customer
and Quotes.TranDate > Invoices.TranDate and 
Quotes.Price <> Invoices.Price order by Quotes.Price desc ) [QuotePrice]
FROM Invoices
group by Invoices.Customer, Invoices.Item

